# Can't add css style and image to html file but don't have any error

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-modal

I have got a question about adding css style and image to html file. I am trying to create my own online page using library flask. I have tried to add css style and image from my computer into html document using following syntax:

```
<!-- Our CSS -->
    <link  href="{{ url_for('static',filename= 'css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

but no change appear ...
here is my link for adding pic

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static' ,filename = 'images/matrix.jpg')}}" alt="">
```

[image]

I also using this but problem still remain

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
```

here is my base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Our CSS -->
    <!-- <link  href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" > -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='css/style.css'/>
    
    <title>My CV</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'navbar.html'%}
    <br/>
    <div class = 'container'>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock%}
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the `{% %}` and the `{{ url_for }}` syntax was not `HTML` syntax

Comment: it's for wtform flask

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you have to write without space.

Try this:

```
<link  href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Or what about this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='css/style.css'/>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: @MaryamMozaffari See edit

Comment: No 
these two didn't work

Comment: @MaryamMozaffari It seems to me that your directory is incorret! Make sure that your directory is correct!

Comment: I really have no idea

Comment: The path of the css file must be relative to the html.

Comment: @MaryamMozaffari ali9428iz

Answer (score 1):

please use **/static/css/style.css** this mean static folder path is like :

```
parent\
|-template\
|  -home.html
|-static\
|  -site.css
```

if you use **static/css/style.css** this mean static folder path is like :

```
parent\
|-template\
|  -home.html
|  -static\
|    -site.css
```

if you use **../static/css/style.css** this mean static folder path is like :

```
parent\
|-template\
|  -home.html
static\
|  -site.css
```

Comment: It doesn't work either
did you saw the picture  ?

Comment: Thank you 
It really helped me
but I had some problem with wtform

Answer (score 0):

As I worked on it
The problem was for WTForm!
so I uninstall and reinstall it
and everything is alright now
I had this error
cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security'
everyone said we should 'pip install werkzeug=0.16.0'
but when I use it my ccs didn't work
by just reinstall flask WTForm I got the answer